# Typescript function type assignment issue

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use using `json-rpc-ws` library in my application and I have problem with a handler function signature which is defined by the library.

The library has following type alias in the declaration file (Connection is an interface):

```
export type Handler<TConnection extends Connection, ParamType, ParamCallbackType> = (this: TConnection, params: ParamType, reply: ReplyCallback<ParamCallbackType>) => void;
export type ReplyCallback<ParamType> = (error: any, params?: ParamType) => void;
```

Now I'm trying to create handler functions in a test code in the following way:

```
// Define a function
const func = (conn: Connection, params: IMyRequest, reply: ReplyCallback<IMyResponse> ) => { }

// Try cast to a handler
const handlerFunc = func as Handler<Connection, IMyRequest, IMyResponse>;
```

However I'm getting an error that `func` cannot be converted to corresponding type. What I'm missing here?

I'm using Typescript 2.8.1 if that make any difference.

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: `[ts] Type '(conn: Connection, params: IMyRequest, reply: ReplyCallback<IMyResponse>) => void' cannot be converted to type 'Handler<Connection, IMyRequest, IMyResponse>'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok yeah I think I got this. In the library's defition file `this` is typed as inherited type for the connection and this is because the handler function is called in this context. However I do not need to explicitly provide that parameter (because it's already defined for `this`) in my handler function.

The correct signature for my function would be:

```
const func = (params: IMyRequest, reply: ReplyCallback<IMyResponse> ) => { }
```

Comment: Exactly. It means that that function is meant to be called in the context of  `Connection` object.